# Is there any way I can change background color of the body using external (linked) css?

Tags: html, css, frontend, styles, background-color

any other way I can change body color except this one

```
<body style="background-color: yellow;">
```

Would prefer to do it externaly with a link to an css file

I tried

```
<style>
.body
{background-color: green;}
```

and nothing changed

Comment: In CSS, the body tag is referenced as `body { .. }`, not `.body { .. }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform an action on a `tag` you have to write the name of the tag alone, when you add a [`selector class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) of a point it looks for a class with that name and then for it to work you had to add `class="body"` like this:

```css
.body {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body class="body"></body>
```

But the correction to what you did is as simple as this without a `.`:

```css
body {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```